# How to fix a warning for UISearchController when navigating out of UITableView using popViewControllerAnimated(true)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisearchcontroller, poptoviewcontroller

The searchController is declared in  `viewDidLoad()` of a TableViewController as `searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)`. When user selects a row in current table view, it navigates out to previous viewcontroller using `self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)`. Whenever this happens i get a warning -

> "Attempting to load the view of a view controller while it is deallocating is not allowed and may result in undefined behavior"

To avoid this, i am removing search controller from superview before calling `popViewControllerAnimated(true)` on navigation controller.

I do not get the same warning if the search is active and a row is selected. May be because i am dismissing the search controller first then popping out to previous controller, so it works fine in this case. But if i dismiss search controller in all cases whether search is active or not, it doesn't help.

Here is the code.

```
//Dismiss searchController if active & Navigate to previous view controller on row selection
if self.searchController.active {
    self.searchController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {
        self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
    })
}
else {
    //remove UISearchController from superView
    self.searchController.view.superview?.removeFromSuperview()
    self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
}
```

I want to understand if this is the right approach as above in else block or should i do the same within :-

1. `viewWillDisappear/viewDidDisappear`
2. `deinit{
           if let superView = searchController.view.superview
           {
               superView.removeFromSuperview()
           }
       }`

Which one is the right thing to do ?

Answer (score 0):

I think first one is better option that check for active before removing it from its superview.